# Compilation error with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a compilation error in one of my projects

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile

because it does not find all the classes from another project that I already included using

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.laberint</groupId>
            <artifactId>laberint-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

and I don't have any compilation problems from Eclipse. I already deleted all the repository.

The errors are because a missing classes that all are in the `laberint-core` artifact. I already deleted the whole repository folder

I also installed the jar

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=laberint-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.laberint -DartifactId=laberint-core -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Please post the `mvn dependency:tree` output.

Comment: Read the error message. Identify the missing class. Find which library it's supposed t be part of. Open the jar file of that library in your Maven repo. Check the class is present at the correct location in the jar file. You have posted nothing that could help us finding the problem: the pom is incomplete, the error message is incomplete, we have no idea of the missing class, of the content of your Maven repo, etc.

Comment: Is `laberint-core` a project of yours and are you developing it in the same `Eclipse` workspace as the project you are trying to build?

Comment: yes, laberint-core a project of mine in the same Eclipse workspace

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a jar from your another project and add it in local lib directory of your current project. Another option is install the jar file in to your local maven repository like below:-

```
 mvn install:yourlocal-jarfile
-Dfile=<path-to-your jar>
-DgroupId=<group-id> --> the group that the file should be registered under
-DartifactId=<artifact-id>  --> give a artifact name to your jar
-Dversion=<version>  --> version of your jar file
-Dpackaging=<packaging> --> jar
-DgeneratePom=true
```

Also you can try with below option:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.laberint</groupId>
        <artifactId>laberint-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <systemPath>/pathto/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this will help your. Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in your comment you are developing the `laberint-core` project in the same `Eclipse` workspace as the project you are trying to build. The problem you have is that while `Eclipse` knows each project in your workspace and can resolve those project dependencies, `Maven` does not have this Information which means that it searches the repositories (your local one in `~/.m2` and `Maven Central`) for the dependency.

As you said, you have already installed the `laberint-core` project to your local `Maven` repository via `mvn install`. That's why `Maven` can find the dependency at all and you do not get a `dependency could not be resolved` exception but I would guess that you installed the dependency some time ago and so some of the classes that your created in the `Eclipse` project after installing are missing.

There are two ways how you can resolve this issue

1. Create and install the dependency `jar` each time before you build the main project

This means some more manual overhead when you are building the main project but it can be automated if you are only building in `Eclipse` and not directly from the command line.

2. Create an aggregator project as shown [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation).

This would basically be a third project that consists only of a `pom.xml` file that looks somewhat like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.laberint</groupId>
  <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>relative/path/to/laberint-core</module>
    <module>relative/path/to/laberint-main</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

To build the project you would then call the goals you called on the main project before on the aggregator project. Basically if you called `mvn package` before from the root directory of the main project you would now change to the root directory of the aggregator project and call `mvn package`. By convention the aggregator pom should lay in the parent directory of its modules.